# How/when does Python destroy objects that are cyclically referenced?

Tags: python

This test program seems to indicate they are not destroyed till program termination:

```
$ cat x.py
from time import sleep

class A:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    self.r = None

  def __del__(self):
    print(f"delete {self.id}")

a1 = A(1)
a1 = None
print("a")
a2 = A(2)
a3 = A(3)
a4 = A(4)
a2.r = a3
a3.r = a2
a4.r = a4
a2 = None
a3 = None
a4 = None
print("b")
sleep(10)
print("c")
sleep(10)
print("d")
sleep(10)
print("e")
$ 
$ python3 x.py
delete 1
a
b
c
d
e
delete 2
delete 3
delete 4
$
```

There is a two-object and a one-object cycle.  The objects in neither are destroyed until program termination.

Comment: Note that there's [no guarantee](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) that `__del__()` will be called at program termination either.

Comment: Python [garbage collector](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-references/) deletes an object if it reference count hits 0.

Comment: Ah, OK, I'm seeing this now:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#module-gc

Comment: For CPython, see https://devguide.python.org/internals/garbage-collector/, which is a pretty complete description of cyclic garbage collection.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis I beg to differ. An object is destroyed when the reference count is 0, but that's not done by the garbage collector. The garbage collector is an additional step that looks for references between otherwise unused objects and destroys them.